# How to select id of rows where other columns differ?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table `data` as follows:

| id | a1 | a2 | a3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | b | 300 | 10 |
| 2 | c | 111 | 12 |
| 3 | b | 300 | 10 |
| 4 | b | 300 | 10 |

Is there a way to select ONLY THOSE ids of rows where information, which is stored in columns **"a1"**,**"a2**,**"a3"**, differ?
In this case, the output should be:

**[1, 2] OR [2, 3] OR [2, 4]**

Doesnt matter wether the representative id of "same rows" was taken from the first one, third one or fourth one.
What I have tried:

```
SELECT id
FROM data
GROUP BY a1, a2, a3;
```

This ofcourse wont work unless I disable **ONLY_GROUP_BY_ALL** mode, however I'd rather not disable such feature and turn to alternatives if those exist.

Comment: Do you understand that the amount of such pairs may be extremely large?

Comment: @Akina sure, but i dont require all of the combinations, only one, it just doesnt matter which one it is since they represent same data in other 3 columns anyway

Comment: You could just use an aggregate on `Id` to get your query to work without disabling full group by, i.e. `SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM data GROUP BY a1, a2, a3;` - If it doesn't matter which Id is returned, the first one seems as good as any. [Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc7d95/1)

Answer (score 0):

As a joke:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t2.id
FROM data t1 
JOIN data t2 ON (t1.a1, t1.a2, t1.a3) <> (t2.a1, t2.a2, t2.a3)
LIMIT 1
```

If some columns may be NULL then

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t2.id
FROM data t1 
JOIN data t2 ON NOT ((t1.a1, t1.a2, t1.a3) <=> (t2.a1, t2.a2, t2.a3))
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: great answer, but solution I am looking for requires t1.id and t2.id to be in the one same column called "id"

Comment: @starter_dev `SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',t1.id,t2.id) AS id FROM ..`